# getAuth() return a object but uid return null when page reload

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My code is so vast; I just put a part of code that I think is essential.

```
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth"

const authFirebase = getAuth()
console.log(authFirebase)

const Home = () => {
  ...
  return(
   ...
  )
}
```

Whenever I reload page (F5) if I just.

```
console.log(authFirebase)
```

I retrieved an object that contains uid in the currentUser property, but when I code like this.

```
 console.log(authFirebase.currentUser.uid)
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')
```

I'm so confused; I didn't understand something about Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason is You’re fetching the user object before that object is ready to be used.

You need to wrap that in a condition if it exists then do log to console.

One more way is to add an observer like onAuthStateChanged this will resolve this problem of prefetching the object.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user =>; {
  if (user) { console.log(user) }
});
```